# WARNING: Django_mysql.w001

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-mysql

I am developing an E-commerce website using Python 3.6. I made a fresh installation of Django 2.0.6 and connected it to a MySQL database (on the localhost) by defining the Database variables in `settings.py` as below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'    : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME'      : 'moda',
        'OPTIONS'   : {
              'init_command'  : "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
              'init_command'  : 'SET innodb_strict_mode=1',
              'charset'       : 'utf8mb4',
        },

        'USER'      : 'root',
        'PASSWORD'  : '',
        'SERVER'    : 'localhost',
        'PORT'      : '3306'

     }
}
```

and after running the `python manage.py check` command using cmd, I am getting the following warning:

```
(django_mysql.W001) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
    HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks.html#django-mysql-w001-strict-mode
```

I even used `' init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"`, and I'm still getting the warning!

I would be so grateful if some expert could show me the right way to fix this!

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of `django-mysql` here.

You have two `'init_command'` keys in the dictionary, so only the second one will be in there after parsing - Python just silently handles duplicates like this. Hint: use `flake8` to lint your source code, as it detects this and warns you.

Additionally, the two `SET` commands can be combined, giving:

```
...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', innodb_strict_mode=1",
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
    },
...
```

HTH!